# rails4-autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, rubygems

Trying to use [this gem](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) for auto completion in my rails 4 app. I'm attempting to have my review form autocomplete an artist name when the user types it in (if it already exists in database).

Following the example, in my reviews controller I put

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :review, :artist
```

in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require_tree .
```

In routes:

```
resources :reviews do
    get :autocomplete_review_artist, :on => :collection
end
```

and at the top of my review form:

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
<% f.autocomplete_field :artist, autocomplete_review_artist_reviews_path %>
```

review model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_presence_of :artist
    validates_presence_of :venue
    validates_presence_of :date

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :concert

end
```

It doesn't work though and when I try to type in an artist name into the form that has already been created, nothing comes up to auto complete it. Any help is appreciated.

I also tried doing it in 2 separate controllers exactly how the example is done. still did not work.

in my artist controller

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  autocomplete :artist, :name
```

then in routes

```
resources :reviews do
    get :autocomplete_artist_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

and review form

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <% f.autocomplete_field :artist, autocomplete_artist_name_reviews_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think youll get a better result by doing it in a JS array improving the responsive.
To do this, you need to render a variable on your controller with .as_json method.

So, in controller(arguments are illustrative):

```
@autocompleteArr = Object.pluck(:property).as_json
```

in view:

```
<%= f.text_field :somefield %>
```

in JS(you cant put it on your application file or even in your html):

```
$('#somefield').autocomplete({source: '<%=raw  @autocompleteArr %>'});
```

You see, even easier and yet preventing ajax loading time that could make your use experience worse in this case.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Created a `artist.js.erb` in `assets/javascripts`
content is:
`$(function() {
    var artists = <%Artist.All.collect{|artist| artist.name}%>
    $( "#artistReview" ).autocomplete({
      source: artists
    });
  });`

Included that in the view. Using include_javascript_tag

gave the field on which autocomplete was required `id: 'artistReview'`

required `jquery-ui` , `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` and `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js` in application.js respectively. and that solved the issue, extensive styling has to be done though

Comment: those other lines were already in there, sorry for not being clear

Comment: any other advice? the documentation seems to be pretty minimal so I'm having trouble finding my issue

Comment: I added it above, pretty standard.

Comment: well the only difference here and their documentation has is that they have the artist in a separate model where as your review has the artist. Give that a try. In fact that is the better practice, create a has_many relationship, artist has many reviews. and give that a try.

Comment: tried that and still did not work, updated original post

Comment: have you checked for error messages in your browser window? related to JavaScript

Comment: honestly I'm not even sure how to know if it's working or not, I'm assuming that once I start typing in an artist's name into the field, it will begin to autocomplete it if the artist already exists in my database? I'm checking this by creating an artist, clearing my browsing history/cache/cookies, then trying to make another review with that same artist. if I don't clear browsing history then browser just autocompletes it obviously

Comment: just open it in chrome and check in console if you get any errors

Comment: If you only require autocomplete on artist name then why don't you use it directly using jquery instead of the gem?

Comment: tried that too haha, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464588/jquery-autocomplete-with-rails-form

Comment: give me your Skype id, lets do it though screen sharing, using the jquery ui.